# How many tiles can be made by us $2 * 5$

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

How many tiles can be made by us $2 * 5$

Comment: Just put your shoulder to the wheel...

Comment: The text in the image seems real.

Comment: So instead of the usual copy/paste we have scan/paste. Ain't technology wonderful! A hint: go about it systematically. The large tiles are the most kludgy, so I would start with that: How many tilings with three Ls, how many with two, and so on? What did you expect? A magic formula? Won't help you in the exam :-(

Comment: I foresee it getting worse; see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6514/139) meta thread.

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing this is by recurrence relation: denote by $a_n$ the number of ways to tile a $2\times n$ grid (you are looking for $a_5$). Denote by $b_n$ the number of ways to tile the grid of height 2, length $n$ in the first row and length $n-1$ in the second (i.e take the original grid and delete he bottom-left corner). Now you get a system of recurrence:
$$\begin{array}{c} a_n=a_{n-1}+3b_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}+b_n \\ b_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+b_{n-1} \end{array}$$
(Those equation come from putting each possible tile in the top left corner)
Can you follow my calculation? If so, find $a_1,a_2,b_1$ and use this equation to find $a_5$ (alternatively, you an solve this system, if you know how to, and plug $n=5$)